# WinRT Gridview with Adjustable tile sizes

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a GridView in my WinRT app that I want to be able to add/remove items on, but also to be able to click on an item and have it dynamically resize to show more information when clicked on. I have attempted to change the height and width of items in a GridView, but they seem to ignore any size change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To accomplish this functionality, your best bet is going to be to try to use a VariableSizedWrapGrid. Check out [this blog](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html) for more info about this.

However, I would not recommend this functionality. If you are looking to show a lot more information, then navigate to a new page. If you are looking to show just a little bit of information, then show a popup. the Music app has a good example of using a popup to show more data.